# Viewing code of a post without enough rep for editing

Tags: feature-request, markdown

Sometimes I find posts that use nice tricks to enhance readability, and I would like to know what is the html/markdown/etc. code behind it, to be able to use it myself.

The only way I found to do that is by editing. But I may not have enough rep. It would be useful to have another option for **viewing code**, without editing.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You don't need rep to edit, only to submit the edit and have it take effect without further review.

Comment: @RobertLongson - You are correct! I had the *edit* link greyed out... I think I might have been not logged in... Will remove the question shortly.

Comment: Don't see why it should be deleted, it may happen to others.

Comment: @RobertLongson - You are correct, again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check you are logged in.

If you are the edit button should be enabled. You don't need rep to click on edit, only to submit the edit and have it take effect without further review.

According to Shadow Wizard when there's a pending suggested edit on a post the link is disabled. That should be temporary though so just check back later.

There are some rare locked questions that can't be edited, they should have a locked message just under the question.

Comment: When there is pending suggested edit on a post the edit link is also disabled.

Comment: And on meta sites where you don't have edit privileges - there are no *suggested* edits (apart from tag wikis).

Answer (score 5):

You can see the source, even if you don't have edit privileges. If you click *edit* you will see the actual source of the post. Make sure not to submit the edit unless you really want to.

Another option is to check the revision history. It has an option *source*.

The URL of the revision history is `https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/POSTID/revisions` where `POSTID` is the ID of the question or answer you can find it in the URL or using the *Share* button). In the case of your question it is https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/257778/revisions. Its source can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/fea28572-e6f7-4c90-9ced-c1fcac95c14e/view-source).

If a question or answer is edited, you can also click the *edited XXX ago* link next to the post flair.